TS2339: Property '$router' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}
I got this errors when pipeline ends. The project runs in my desktop locally, but when i run pipeline thats brokens with error. I've already tried downloading all the dependencies again and even tried reinstalling the vue router. but the pipeline still does not pass, it returns such an error:
TS2339: Property '$router' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}, { getProfile: () => Promise<void>; setToken: (token: any, refresh: any) => void; doLogout: (opts?: { expired: boolean; }) => void; refreshToken: () => Promise<void>; doLogin: ({ username, password }: { ...; }) => Promise<...>; init: () => Promise<...>; }, ... 17 more ..., {}>'. #17 39.50     69 |     logout() { #17 39.50     70 |       this.doLogout() #17 39.50   > 71 |       this.$router.push('/'); #17 39.50        |            ^^^^^^^ #17 39.50     72 |     } #17 39.50     73 |   }, #17 39.50     74 |   setup() {

i've tried to reinstall all packages, reinstall vue-router

Could you provide a minimal, complete and reproducible example of a code that causes the issue, instead of just adding the error message to the question?

This was due to the previous release of vue (3.36), it's been fixed now.. Just delete your package lock and node_modules and reinstall
However you have to pin vue-router to 4.4.0 for now
See links here for details
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/28440
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/28373
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/pull/28446
